# Django: using more than one database with inspectdb?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, inspectdb

My settings file's database section looks like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'C:/Users/Desktop/test.db'
    },
    'blah':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'C:/Users/Desktop/test2.db'
    }
}
```

When I run the command `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py`, I only get the model generated for the default database, but not the second one. How could I get both models generated?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb):

> `--database DATABASE`
>
> Specifies the database to introspect. Defaults to `default`.

So you can inspect your second database with:

```
python manage.py inspectdb --database blah
```

You cannot inspect both at the same time.

Comment: When I try this I'm getting an error that `Connection 'blah' doesn't exist`. Do I need to do something prior to this? Does the directory I'm in matter?

Comment: That would happen if the database file didn't exist. Check that `'C:/Users/Desktop/test2.db'` actually exists?

Answer (score 11):

You can specify a specific database like this:

```
python manage.py inspectdb --database=blah > you_app/models.py
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying [@solarissmoke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37581914/10605163) for Django 2.*:

Don't wrap the database name with quotes, otherwise it will give you a `KeyError` and a `ConnectionDoesnotExist` error.

```
python manage.py inspectdb --database blah
```