# Managing User Authentication Across Multiple Django Projects with a Custom User Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have three Django projects: Project A, Project B, and Project C. Project A serves as the authentication project, Project B is responsible for managing user-related functionalities, and Project C handles restaurant-related operations.

In Project A, I have created a custom user model to suit my authentication requirements. Now, I want to utilize this custom user model to access the APIs of both Project B and Project C.

How can I achieve this integration between the projects? Specifically, I would like to accomplish the following:

Enable user authentication: I want to use the custom user model defined in Project A to authenticate users when they access the APIs of Project B and Project C.

Share user information: I need to access user information from Project B and Project C using the custom user model defined in Project A. This includes retrieving user details, updating user profiles, and performing user-related operations.

Maintain consistency: It is essential to ensure that any changes made to the custom user model in Project A are reflected across all projects, including Project B and Project C.

Here is my Custom user Model from Project A.

```
import uuid

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        now = timezone.now()
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(
            email=email,
            is_staff=is_staff,
            is_active=True,
            is_superuser=is_superuser,
            last_login=now,
            date_joined=now,
            **extra_fields
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        user = self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    # username = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    organization_id = models.UUIDField(null=True, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%i/" % (self.pk)
```

**I have already tried this solution  ( [Using same database table with two different projects Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69579575/using-same-database-table-with-two-different-projects-django) ). But it is not working. Or somehow I am not implemented it correctly. If this is the solution please give a full example of it.**your text****