# whats the right way for read MySQL database with django

Tags: python, mysql, django, digital-ocean, pymysql

I'm new to django

I have a local application I wrote in python that writes scientific data to a MySQL database hosted on a digital ocean droplet that also runs django.

I'm experiencing an intermittent problem where occasionally (maybe 1 in 3 tries) a page request produces a 'bad gateway' error message. Refreshing the page will normally produces the correct page.  A page example is http://104.131.165.99/garage/

The problem is annoying and I'm not sure what the cause is but I never understood models in django and I'm not sure how to even clearly ask my question.

My local application uses pymysql to connect to the MySQL database thats part of the server where django is hosted, in otherwords a mysql database thats NOT(?) really associated with the instance of django running on the server.

The code in my django app (see below) that runs when a page is requested uses pymysql with a host address of 127.0.0.1 to read and manipulate the MwSQL data.

Whether or not this is the cause of my problem, I always wondered if this was the proper way to read mysql data in django considering the app writing to that database is on a different server.

this is my code that returns the html doc...as its probably obvious i'm not a programmer by trade

thank you in advance for your consideration.

```
def get_temp_dict(location):

  ##### start clock ###########
  start_time=0
  start_time=time.perf_counter()

  ##### get db user data ###########
  user_data=get_user_data()

  mysql_user = user_data['mysql_user']
  mysql_password = user_data['mysql_password']
  mysql_database = user_data['mysql_database']

  ##### constants ###########
  filepath="/home/django/django_project/django_project/media/"
  filename="GRAPH_" + location + ".png"
  filename_and_path=filepath+filename
  short_filename_path="/media/"+filename
  now = datetime.now()
  formatted_date = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


  cur_date=dt.datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
  queryString="SELECT sensor_id, label, temp, time, date FROM temps INNER JOIN sensors USING (sensor_id) where label=" + "'" + location + "'" +"and date=" + "'" + formatted_date +"' order by 'time' ASC"

  ##### connect to database ###########
  try:
    db = pymysql.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user=mysql_user, password=mysql_password, database=mysql_database)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("USE hms")
    SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query(queryString, db)
    df = pd.DataFrame(SQL_Query, columns=['sensor_id', 'temp', 'time', 'date'])

    STATUS1="success2"

  except: 
    STATUS1="failure"

  #### build dataframe ###########

  timestring=str(df.at[df.time.size-1,'time'])
  convert_time=datetime.strptime(timestring, '%H:%M:%S')
  latest_record_timestamp=datetime.strftime(convert_time, '%I:%M %p')

  date_str=str(df.at[df.time.size-1,'date'])
  convert_date= datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
  latest_record_datestamp=datetime.strftime(convert_date, '%b %d')
  latest_record_temp=str(df.at[df.time.size-1,'temp'])+ u"\N{DEGREE SIGN}"

  str_max_temp=str(df['temp'].max())

  time_obj_max_time_temp=datetime.strptime(str(df.at[df['temp'].idxmax(),'time']), '%H:%M:%S')
  str_max_time_temp=datetime.strftime(time_obj_max_time_temp,'%I:%M %p')
  
  date_obj_max_date=datetime.strptime(str(df.at[df['temp'].idxmax(),'date']), '%Y-%m-%d')
  str_max_date_temp=datetime.strftime(date_obj_max_date, '%b %d')

  str_min_temp=str(df['temp'].min())

  obj_min_time_temp=datetime.strptime(str(df.at[df['temp'].idxmin(),'time']),'%H:%M:%S' )
  str_min_time_temp=datetime.strftime(obj_min_time_temp,'%I:%M %p')


  obj_min_date_temp=datetime.strptime(str(df.at[df['temp'].idxmin(),'date']), '%Y-%m-%d')
  str_min_date_temp=datetime.strftime(obj_min_date_temp, '%b %d')

  first_record_time_string=df.at[1,'time']
  first_record_time_object=datetime.strptime(first_record_time_string, '%H:%M:%S')


  ######### Build HTML doc ##################
  
  message='NOTE, this ' + location +' temperature data report was was produced with data as recent as ' + str(latest_record_timestamp) +' on ' + str(latest_record_datestamp)  + ' where the current temperature was: ' + latest_record_temp
  MSG2="so far there have been " + str(df.time.size) + " Readings today, with the first reading at " + str(datetime.strftime(first_record_time_object,'%I:%M %p'))
  html_doc=html_status_page()

  b = {'names': 'TIMOTHY', 'CUR_DATE': str(cur_date),'STATUS1':STATUS1, 'MESSAGE':str(message),
      'TEMP1':latest_record_temp,'LOCATION1':location, 'filename_and_path':short_filename_path, 
       'str_max_temp':str_max_temp, 'str_max_time_temp':str_max_time_temp,
      'str_max_date_temp':str_max_date_temp, 'str_min_temp':str_min_temp,
      'str_min_time_temp':str_min_time_temp, 'str_min_date_temp':str_min_date_temp,
      'MSG2':MSG2 }
      
  for x,y in b.items():
      html_doc = html_doc.replace(x, y)

  df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time)
  plt.figure(figsize=(14,4))
  g=sns.lineplot(x='time', y='temp', data=df,color="darkblue")

  plt.ylim(df['temp'].min()-1, df['temp'].max()+1)
  plt.xticks(rotation=45)
  # compensate for axis labels getting clipped off
  plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=.5, left=0.15)

  g.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%I %p'))

  g.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval = 2))

  #create unique filename based on time
  plt.savefig(filename_and_path)

  endtime=int(time.perf_counter()-start_time)
  c={'TOTALTIME':str(endtime)}
  for a,b in c.items():
    html_doc = html_doc.replace(a, b)

  return html_doc
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to define the remote database in Django settings and use Django models to access that information.

I think following links might be useful for you.

How to use multiple databases in Django.
[Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/multi-db/)

Creating Django models from an existing database.
[Similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37581885/django-using-more-than-one-database-with-inspectdb)

Finally, you can refer to Django MVT architecture on how to use views, models and templates to display a page.

Comment: I know its always easier to say read the docs or google it, I just wanted a hint if I was wrong and u took the time to read/respond.  thank you so much :)